# Error when using CreatedAtRoute in ASP.NET Core minimal API

Tags: asp.net-core, routes

I'm trying to use `CreatedAtRoute` in minimal API.

```cs
app.MapGet("/clients/{id:int}", [EndpointName("GetClientById")] async (int id, ClientsContext db) =>
  await db.Clients.SingleOrDefaultAsync(client => client.Id == id));

app.MapPost("/clients", async (ClientsContext db, Client client) =>
{
  var newClient = db.Add(client);
  await db.SaveChangesAsync();
  var entity = newClient.Entity;
  var url = $"{host}/clients/{newClient.Entity.Id}";
  return Results.CreatedAtRoute(
    routeName:   "GetClientById",
    routeValues: new { id = entity.Id  },
    value:       entity);
});
```

I use `EndpointName` attribute to name the endpoint I refer to in POST request.
However, I get the exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: No route matches the supplied values.

This is strange since there's only one parameter in url pattern - `id`.

#### A little note

You can use `WithName` instead of `[EndpointName]` attribute:

```cs
app
  .MapGet("/clients-m/{id:int}", async (int id, ClientsContext db) =>
    await db.ClientsM.SingleOrDefaultAsync(client => client.Id == id))
  .WithName("GetClientByIdAsync");
```

Comment: Change routeName to `GetClientByIdAsync` - any changes?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary That works! Worth +1! 

Comment: I’ll type up an answer soon :)

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary OK! 

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary I also found out that I could use `WithName` method on `MapGet`. 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For minimal APIs, try using [`.WithName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.routingendpointconventionbuilderextensions.withname?view=aspnetcore-6.0#microsoft-aspnetcore-builder-routingendpointconventionbuilderextensions-withname-1(-0-system-string)) instead for setting the `EndpointNameAttribute` i.e.

```cs
app.MapGet("/clients/{id:int}", async (int id, ClientsContext db) =>
  await db.Clients.SingleOrDefaultAsync(client => client.Id == id))
.WithName("GetClientById");
```